# Yii zii.widgets.grid.cgridview with type html render failed

Tags: php, yii

I use this grid to view a table with data:

View part:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'news-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(       
        array(
            'name'=>'enable',
            'type'=>'html',
            'value'=>'$data->stateHtmlIcon',
        ),      
    ),
)); ?>
```

In my model:

```
public function getStateHtmlIcon() {
        if ($this->enable == AbstractModel::ENABLE) {
            return '<font class="icon-enable"></font>';
        } else {
            return '<font class="icon-disable"></font>';
        }
    }
```

It doesn't work, the render stop when display column with stateHtmlIcon.

When I comment 'type'=>'html' in the grid (view part), it works but in the column the html is not rendered correctly

```
<font class="icon-enable"></font>
```

instead of icon displayed with css style.

So I think I don't use correctly 'type'=>'html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently used

```
array(
  'type' => 'raw',
  'value' => 'CHtml::link([...])',
),
```

which does the job.

See also

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataColumn#type-detail

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFormatter

Comment: Thanks. I had tried with raw and without result :( But now, I retry and it works!!! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use 'raw' as the type. see [CFormatter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFormatter)

raw: the attribute value will not be changed at all.